# Two different servers generates half different hash with sha1

Tags: php, sha1, wechat

I'm trying to implement a php authentication algorithm for WeChat, code was copied from their documentation here: https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki?t=resource/res_main&id=mp1421135319&token=&lang=zh_CN

Basically, a service that sends few parameters and a hashed secret and compare the result that is generated with a token on the server.

I was trying to make the authentication but it fails every time. I've looked for the request, extracted the parameters and tried to back trace the code.

```
$signature = '000a2ad000ce0000a8325206deba18d04b602085';
$timestamp = '1477497908';
$nonce = '876122376';
$token = 'spotops';


 $tmpArr = array($token, $timestamp, $nonce);
 sort($tmpArr, SORT_STRING);
 $tmpStr = implode( $tmpArr );
 $tmpStr = sha1( $tmpStr );

        echo  '1: '.$tmpStr . "\r\n";
        echo '2: ' . $signature ;
```

Surprisingly - I got this result:

> 1: 503a2ad085ce4386**a8325206deba18d04b602085**
>
> 2: 000a2ad000ce0000**a8325206deba18d04b602085**

As you can see only the second half of the string is the same, while the first 16 characters are different.

This is, as you can probably guess, very frustrating as the authentication function will always fail.

I did test the same code on different server (PHP 5.6.24, the first one runs 5.6.13 as far as I can remember) and I'm getting a correct response there.

So it looks like I'm missing something and as the other part of the string are the same I can only assume this is something with the Sha1 function - but I'm not sure what.

Any help or Idea, preferably, such that does not require to upgrade the PHP version on the server, will be appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly does `$signature` come from? The amount of zeroes in it looks quite suspicious to me.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the numeric values of the first 16 chars have been set to 0 some how

Comment: I'm getting these in a $_GET request. I assume the other side generates the SHA1 key with the same params that are also attached to the same url.

Comment: Actually, I'm assuming this is the issue, as I'm catching the data using incapsula real time service.

Comment: Did you executed the same code in both machine, with 'hardcoded' variables values? What is the value of $tmpStr in both machines before the `sha1` function?

Comment: I've printed the $tmpStr in both machines, also the sorted and the unsorted array, Both servers return the same output. only difference is the SHa1